# Conflicting dependencies error when adding zxing-android-embedded & zxing-core in app to create QR image

Tags: android, kotlin, dependencies, qr-code, zxing

I'm trying to make an app in Kotlin which scans a QR Code, generates a PDF with the result of the scan at the centre of the page & adds below it a `125x125 px` QR Code image of the same text (essentially the qr code which was scanned) & then stores the file in my Downloads folder. I am using `PdfDocument` class for PDF generation, `com.github.yuriy-budiyev:code-scanner:2.3.2` dependency for scanning QR Code, and the Zxing library to generate the QR Code image for the PDF.

The problem I am facing is when I add below dependencies for the zxing library in my `build.gradle` file,

```
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
```

I am getting an error when my app builds which essentially says - *(full error : https://pastebin.com/m6Vj0bAJ)*

```
Duplicate class com.google.zxing.Result found in modules zxing-core-3.4.1.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.4.1) and zxing-android-embedded-3.6.0.jar (com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0)
```

Here is what the dependencies in my `build.gradle` file look like -

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'com.github.yuriy-budiyev:code-scanner:2.3.2' //for scanning qr
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
}
```

And the imports & code I am using for generating qr code with zxing lib. in my kotlin code -

```
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeEncoder

//code in the function which creates the PDF using PdfDocument lib.

val qrCodeWriter = QRCodeWriter()
val bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 125, 125)
val barcodeEncoder = BarcodeEncoder()
val qrCodeBitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix)
val qrCodeX = (pageInfo.pageWidth - qrCodeBitmap.width) / 2f
val qrCodeY = y + textBounds.height() + 20f
canvas.drawBitmap(qrCodeBitmap, qrCodeX, qrCodeY, null)
```

---

Everything works fine if I don't do the whole qrcode image in pdf part; When I added the two dependencies I mentioned for the zxing lib., my build failed with the error I mentioned above. What went wrong here?

Comment: `zxing-android-embedded` 3.6.0 appears to have `zxing:core` 3.3.2 as a dependency. So you're getting duplicate copies of that dependency since you specified that you wanted 3.4.1. You could try switching to 3.3.2 instead, or use `implementation ('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0') { transitive false }` and see if that works.

Comment: Hi @Michael! This worked perfectly, everything's solved. Can you add your comment as an answer this post so I can mark it ✅? Thanks a ton! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/3.6.0), `zxing-android-embedded` 3.6.0 has a dependency to `zxing:core` 3.3.2.
You've added `zxing:core` 3.4.1 as a dependency, so you're getting duplicate copies of `zxing:core`.

There are a couple of different possible solutions:

- Use the same version of `zxing:core` (i.e. 3.3.2) that `zxing-android-embedded` does.
- Remove the transitive dependencies of `zxing-android-embedded`, so only your version (3.4.1) of `zxing:core` is used:
  `implementation ('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0') { transitive false }`
   Note: This may or may not work, depending on whether `zxing-android-embedded` is compatible with any other versions of its dependencies.

Comment: `implementation ('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0') { transitive false }` has worked perfectly for me. Thanks!